# Exposed domain model in Java microservice architecture

Tags: jpa, entity, microservices, dto

I'm aware that copying entity classes and properties into DTOs is considered anti-pattern, so by `Exposed domain model` pattern the same `@Entity` can be used as both database entity class, and DTO for service and MVC layer. (see here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93511/data-transfer-objects-vs-entities-in-java-rest-server-application)

But suppose we have microservice architecture where the same set of properties is used as entity in one project with persistence, and as DTO in another project which uses the first one as a service. What's the proposed pattern in such a situation?
Because the second project doesn't need `@Entity` related functionality, and if we put that class in shared library, it will be tied unnecessary to JPA specific APIs and libraries. And the alternative is to again use separate DTO classes anti-pattern.

Comment: Do you ever understand that response you are referring to? It's just weird, saying "use exposed model over DTOs" when exposed model just says "use POJOs + repository instead of logic-carrying DAOs". I mean, no one says you cannot use more POJOs on top of "exposed model" but for some reason the response discourages that. What if I, say, store localizable texts as codes in my model objects but want to expose those as strings to my clients? Clearly I will need different DTO for client interaction that the one I use for persistence.

Comment: Why not check this out? https://cassiomolin.com/2016/03/23/why-you-should-use-dtos-in-your-rest-api/ - some arguments about why DTOs make more sense than exposing model directly. It's really disgusting to see a POJO carrying four sets of annotations, one for JPA persistence, one for swagger, one for REST API and one more for storing in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

When your requirements for a DTO model exactly match your entity model you are either in a very early stage of the project or very lucky that you just have a simple model. If your model is very simple, then DTOs won't give you many immediate benefits.

At some point, the requirements for the DTO model and the entity model will diverge though. Imagine you add some audit aspects, statistics or denormalization to your entity/persistence model. That kind of data is usually never exposed via DTOs directly, so you will need to split the models. It is also often the case that the main driver for DTOs is the fact that you don't need all the data all the time. If you display objects in e.g. a dropdown you only need a label and the object id, so why would you load the whole entity state for such a use case?

The fact that you have annotations on your DTO models shouldn't bother you that much, what is the alternative? An XML-like mapping? Manual object wiring?
If your model is used by third parties directly, you could use a subclassing i.e. keep the main model free of annotations and have annotated subclasses in your project that extend the main model.

Since implementing a DTO approach correctly, I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which will not only simplify the way you define DTOs, but it will also improve the performance of your queries.

If you are interested, I even have an example for an [external model](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-storage/blob/master/rest/model/src/main/java/com/blazebit/storage/rest/model/AccountRepresentation.java) that uses [entity view subclasses](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-storage/blob/master/rest/impl/src/main/java/com/blazebit/storage/rest/impl/view/AccountRepresentationView.java) to keep the main model clean.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, but emphasize in the question is on microservice (MS) architecture and reusing defined entity POJOs from one MS in another as POJOs. From what I've read on microservices it's closely related to another question - should MSs share any common functionality and classes at all, or be completely independent? It seems there is no definite agreement on it, and also no definite answer, or widely accepted pattern, to this.

From my recent experience here is what I adopted, and it works well so far.
Have common functionality across MSs - yes, in form of a commons project added as dependency to all MSs, with its dependencies set as optional. Share entity classes (expose them in commons) - no.

The main reason is that entity classes are closely related to data store for particular MS. And as the established rule is that MSs shouldn't share data stores, then it makes sense not to share entity classes for those data stores. It helps MSs to be more independent, and freedom to manage their data store in their own way. It means some more typing to add additional DTO classes and conversion between them, but it's a trade-off worth taking to retain MS independence. Reasons Christian Beikov and  Maksim Gumerov mentioned apply as well.

What we do share (put in commons) are some common functionality and helper classes (for cloud, discovery, error handling, rest and json configuration...), and pure DTOs, where T is transfer between MSs (rest entities or message payloads).